# Baseline profile is not avaliable on Android S

Tags: android, baseline-profile, macrobenchmark

I generate a baseline profile according to [guidance of baseline profile](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles#creating-profile-rules) and want to install my app on Android S devices without Google Play. I found the baseline profile is not available. dump the info of baseline profile by profman command and it shows:

```
profman : Error when reading profile: Profile version mismatch.
```

The version of profman on Android S is V015 while the generated baseline profile is V010.

So, the question is, how to make baseline profile available on Android S without the Google Play installation process.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to use one of the latest AGP versions (7.3.0).
On top of that, when generating and installing the profile, use one of the latest versions of Macrobenchmark and the Profile Installer library.

```
implementation("androidx.benchmark:benchmark-macro-junit4:1.1.0")
implementation("androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.2.0")
```

In these versions a bug was fixed which caused the problem you're describing.

Comment: Uploading AGP and gradle fixed the issue for me. For anyone wondering which AGP version matches which version of Gradle, here's a tiny list: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle